# How can optimize this VIEW Statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, view, query-optimization

I have two tables table1 and table2. Table1 is generated by a parser and automatically updated every few days. Table2 is the user edited version of table1. If a record exist in table2, that should overlay the record in table1 in the view.

Any edited version in table2 has the original content from table1 for Column2 and Column3 in OldColumn2 and OldColumn3 respectively. When a user deletes a record, the deleted column has value `1` and if the user wants to add the record again it has value `0` to display in the view. By default the value is `NULL` if it's never been deleted.

If an new record in inserted into table2, OldColumn2 and OldColumn3 has the value `new` string to distinguish that the record doesn't exist in table1.

Here is the design of my table.

```
Table1
+------+------+------+-------------+
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | OtherColumns|
+------+------+------+-------------+
|   a1 |   b1 |   c1 |    Data     |
+------+------+------+-------------+
|   a2 |   b2 |   c2 |    Data     |
+------+------+------+-------------+
|   a3 |   b3 |   c3 |    Data     |
+------+------+------+-------------+
|   a4 |   b4 |   c4 |    Data     |
+------+------+------+-------------+


Table2
+------+------+------+-------------+----------+----------+---------+
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | OtherColumns| OldCol2  |  OldCol3 | Deleted |
+------+------+------+-------------+----------+----------+---------+
|  a1  |   e1 |  f1  |   Data      |    b1    |     c1   |   NULL  |
+------+------+------+-------------+----------+----------+---------+
|  a2  |   k2 |  m2  |   Data      |    b2    |     c2   |   0     |
+------+------+------+-------------+----------+----------+---------+
|  a3  |   k3 |  m3  |   Data      |    b3    |     c3   |   1     |
+------+------+------+-------------+----------+----------+---------+
|  z1  |   kk |  jj  |   Data      |   new    |   new    |   1     |
+------+------+------+-------------+----------+----------+---------+
|  z2  |   kj |  uu  |   Data      |   new    |   new    |   0     |
+------+------+------+-------------+----------+----------+---------+

    View
+------+------+------+-------------+----------+----------+---------+
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | OtherColumns| OldCol2  |  OldCol3 | Deleted |
+------+------+------+-------------+----------+----------+---------+
|  a1  |   e1 |  f1  |   Data      |    b1    |     c1   |   NULL  |
+------+------+------+-------------+----------+----------+---------+
|  a2  |   k2 |  m2  |   Data      |    b2    |     c2   |   0     |//Deleted then added
+------+------+------+-------------+----------+----------+---------+
|  a4  |   k4 |  j4  |   Data      |    NULL  |     NULL |   0     |
+------+------+------+-------------+----------+----------+---------+
|  z2  |   kj |  uu  |   Data      |   new    |   new    |   0     |
+------+------+------+-------------+----------+----------+---------+
```

Here is my view statement.

```
CREATE VIEW NEWVIEW
AS
SELECT t2.* FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.column1 = t2.column1 AND t1.column2 = t2.oldColumn2 AND t1.column3 = t2.oldColumn3
WHERE t2.column1 IS NOT NULL AND t2.Deleted = 0

UNION

SELECT t1.*, null, null, null FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.column1 = t2.column1 AND t1.column2 = t2.oldColumn2 AND t1.column3 = t2.oldColumn3
WHERE t2.column1 IS NULL

UNION

SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE oldColumn2 = 'new' AND oldColumn3 = 'new' AND Deleted = 0
```

The view is a bit slow right now. How can I optimize this view?

Comment: This porcess screams change the design. Why aren't you just adding the new data to table 2 from table1?

Comment: Table1 is generated by a parser. They way the parser is designed it deletes EVERYTHING from table1 and rebuilds it again(I inherited that). So any user generated content has to be stored in another table. If the user edits the content from table1 then it's stored in table2. Hope that makes it clear.

Comment: How do you distinguish that row a1 has not been deleted but that a2 has been deleted then added again for your view? Or is there a mistake in your Table2? And do you care about order?

Comment: @jswolf19 I distinguish it using a composite key that never changes in both the tables. The composite key is in the `OtherColumns`. There are over 25 columns and I didn't want to write all of it as it's not required. The order doesn't really matter. If `deleted=1` then it will not show in the view. But if it's `0` or `null` it will be displayed. At first deleted `IS NULL` if they delete it, it's `1` and if they add the record instead of adding a new record i query the db and the change the value to `0` so it doesn't create duplicates and it's added in the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change first two SELECT statements in your view with this one -

```
SELECT
  t1.column1,
  t1.column2,
  t1.column3,
  IF(t2.column1 IS NULL, t1.OtherColumns, t2.OtherColumns) OtherColumns,
  IF(t2.column1 IS NULL, NULL, t2.OldCol2) OldCol2,
  IF(t2.column1 IS NULL, NULL, t2.OldCol3) OldCol3,
  IF(t2.column1 IS NULL, NULL, t2.Deleted) Deleted
FROM
  table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
  ON t1.column1 = t2.column1 AND t1.column2 = t2.oldColumn2 AND t1.column3 = t2.oldColumn3
WHERE 
  t2.column1 IS NULL OR t2.column1 IS NOT NULL AND t2.Deleted = 0
```

Note, than views may have bad performance.

Comment: You might also get a slight boost if you use `union all` since you shouldn't have any overlap between the two/three queries.

Comment: This doesn't really help there is only a second or two difference